# SQL: Get all rows where a logically linked columns (by their title) contains specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table like this:

| Part-ID | ProjectA_Responsible | ProjectA_Result | ProjectB_Responsible | ProjectB_Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Smith | done | Simpson | open |
| 203 | Simpson | open | Smith | open |
| 304 | Simpson | done | Smith | open |
| 440 | Smith | open | Johnson | done |

The title of the column shows that there are 2 projects (ProjectA, ProjectB) and a responsible for each one. The names of the colums will always be like that, so if a ProjectC would exist, 2 additional coumns with the names **"ProjectC_Responsible"** and **"ProjectC_Result"** would get added.

I want to get all IDs where "Simpson" has to do something, so the "Result" of his project is "open".
So in my example I want to get:

| Part-ID | ProjectA_Responsible | ProjectA_Result | ProjectB_Responsible | ProjectB_Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Smith | done | Simpson | open |
| 203 | Simpson | open | Smith | open |

I currently do not have an idea how to do this with a SQL statement. I'm using a MS Access frontend in the background so I may also solve it later with VBA, but I hope there is a direct solution with an SQL statement?

Comment: Are you open to re-designing the table(s) - as that’s not how relational tables are normally designed and it is your design that is making the query more difficult than it needs to be?

Comment: No and yes ;) I would prefer not to re-design the tables. At the time I created it I had no better approach and now it would make a huge effort to change it back. If there is no way around it, I would do it. But I prefer not to do it.

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: @karlo922 To keep it simple & logical, ANYBODY WUD ADVISE YOU TO RESDESIGN THE TABLE.
Simply, change it to CREATE TABLE TableName {partId, ProjectName, projectResponsible, projectResult}

By doing this, you can add as many projects as you want without needing to change table structure for every project.

Please do it

Comment: No, that's not how it works. If the OP has a big running database that has been used by his company for decades, and that has lots of dependencies, you just don't change it from one day to another for the sake of making a single query simpler. Redesigning is money expensive and time consuming. In general I would never attempt to change the OP's schema unless the query becomes **very** inefficient so that asking for a redesign possibility may make sense.

Comment: Can you not just do a bit of and/or logic `WHERE (ProjectA_Responsible = 'Simpson' AND ProjectA_Result = 'open' OR ProjectB_Responsible = 'Simpson' AND ProjectB_Result = 'open')`

Comment: @Charlieface I think op is trying to say that they could have 1-N projects and they want to automatically have a query which works regardless of how many project columns they have.

Comment: @DaleK - correct. I now will solve it with VBA together with the answer of Gufus as there seems to be no direct way to do this automatically with SQL alone. To rework the table scheme is a huge effort (not the table data itself, but the relying frontend etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from [TableName]
where (ProjectA_Responsible = 'Simpson' and ProjectA_Result = 'open')
or (ProjectB_Responsible = 'Simpson' and ProjectB_Result = 'open')
```

Comment: I do not know why I did not find this myself. Thank you very much. I thought I can do this with 1-N projects directly with SQL so I did not see this obvious solution. So I will create a WHERE statement like you proposed with VBA. With VBA I will be able to do this programmatically for all given projects so I create the SQL string with all given projects.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you have a problem with your table design, this design is not scalable, and requires you to change the table structure and queries every time you add a new project.

You can use another table with a correct design and transfer the existing data to it with a simple query. consider the following:

```
create table NewTable (Part_ID int, Project_Title nvarchar(50),Project_Responsible nvarchar(50),
Project_Result nvarchar(50));

insert into NewTable 
Select Part_ID,'Project A',ProjectA_Responsible,ProjectA_Result From OldTable;
insert into NewTable 
Select Part_ID,'Project B',ProjectB_Responsible,ProjectB_Result From OldTable;
```

Repeat the `insert into NewTable Select... From OldTable` according to the number of projects you have.

Now you can simply query the new table as the following:

```
Select Part_ID, Project_Title,Project_Responsible,Project_Result From NewTable 
where Project_Responsible='Simpson' and Project_Result='open'
```

See a demo from [***here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3c9fbec0c1f463913a52c98c6bb37db).

Comment: "*At the time I created it I had no better approach and now it would make a huge effort to change it back.*" - You shouldn't change OP's schema if that is not a contemplated option by the OP for the solution of this problem.

Comment: @lemon, I thought that he didn't mind to change the table design, and his problem with the data that already entered.

Comment: @lemon Showing the best way to solve this problem still helps others, even if it doesn't work for OP.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal but this changed table scheme would make other issues for my database. So I will use the answer of @Gufus.

Comment: @karlo922, You are welcome, actually, this approach is proposed  to solve the problem of adding new projects to the table not only for selecting the required data. Using the correct DB schema will ease the process of maintenance and future updates.